# where() in underscore didn't work as expected

Tags: node.js, underscore.js

I have some problem to use _.where(). It didn't work as expected. 
Here is my example JSON,

```
var result = [
  {
    image: {
      id: 158,
      ig_id: "968545232755317101_1532289565",
      status: "hide",
    },
    id: 1,
    month: 4,
    year: 2015
  },
  {
    image: {
      id: 152,
      ig_id: "968547282620733844_1532289565",
      status: "approve",
    },
    id: 2,
    month: 4,
    year: 2015
  },
]
```

I want to get collection where image.status = 'hide'. I did like this,

```
console.log(_.where(result.image, { status : 'hide'})); // This return []
console.log(_.where(result, { image.status : 'hide'})); // This will error
console.log(_.where(result, { 'image.status' : 'hide'})); // This return []
```

I don't know how to do it in the right way. I really need help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with vanilla JS like this:

```
console.log(result.filter(function (value) { 
    return value.image.status === 'hide'; 
}));
```

I don't believe Underscore.js supports deep comparisons in `where()`, but if you use lodash, this works:

```
console.log(_.where(result, { image: {status : 'hide'}}));
```